# Show one div, hide all others on click

Tags: jquery

I have a simple image/video gallery that I want to animate with jQuery. All I want to be able to do is, when someone clicks a link the `.big` div with the same ID is set to `display:block; opacity:1` and all the other divs are set to `display:none; opacity:0`

This is the markup for my gallery;

```
<div id="gallery">

    <div class="main">

        <div id="big-1" class="big"><!-- image / video here --></div>
        <div id="big-2" class="big"><!-- image / video here --></div>
        <div id="big-3" class="big"><!-- image / video here --></div>

    </div>

    <div class="thumbnails">

        <a id="1" href="#"><img src="images/thumb1.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
        <a id="2" href="#"><img src="images/thumb1.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
        <a id="3" href="#"><img src="images/thumb1.jpg" alt="#"/></a>

    </div>

</div>
```

By default all the `.big` divs are set to `display:none; opacity:0` except the first one.

Comment: You can hide all .big [ $('.big') ] classes and then show in the only the div by id [ $('#div' + id) ] on "complete" callback".

Comment: Do not use same ID for multiple elements. Its terrible.

Comment: You want thumbnail also to be displayed according to `.big` clicked or just want to display clicked `.big`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simpler solution whithout the need of ids or random attributes:

The HTML:

```
<div id="gallery">
<div class="main">
    <div class="big show"><!-- image / video here --></div>
    <div class="big"><!-- image / video here --></div>
    <div class="big"><!-- image / video here --></div>
</div>

<div class="thumbnails">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/thumb1.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="images/thumb1.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="images/thumb1.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.thumbnails a').on('click',function(){
   var eq = $(this).index();

   $('.main .big').removeClass('show');
   $('.main .big').eq(eq).addClass('show');
});
```

Basically what it does it get the position of the thumbnail clicked and then show the gallery element in the same position (adding a class `.show` which have `display:block` for example).

Here is a **[flavored FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mbGv8/)** ilustrating the approach.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have several elements with the same ID, which is wrong. Each ID on the page should be unique.

Then you could do something like this:

```
<div class="main">

    <div id="vid1" class="big"><!-- image / video here --></div>
    <div id="vid2" class="big"><!-- image / video here --></div>
    <div id="vid3" class="big"><!-- image / video here --></div>

</div>

<div class="thumbnails">

    <a id="1" class="vidlink" href="#"><img src="images/thumb1.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a id="2" class="vidlink" href="#"><img src="images/thumb1.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a id="3" class="vidlink" href="#"><img src="images/thumb1.jpg" alt="#"/></a>

</div>
<script>
    $('a.vidlink').click(function(){
        $('div.main div').css('opacity',0).css('display','none');
        $('div.main div#vid'+this.attr('id')).css('opacity',1).css('display','block');
    });
</script>
```

But I higly recommend just using jquery's `.hide()` and `.show()` functions.

Answer (score 1):

ID cannot be alone numeric.

Conventions for ID:

> Must contain at least one character
>
> Must not contain any space characters
>
> Do NOT start an ID name with a number
>
> ID must be unique.

Try:

HTML:

```
<div id="gallery">

    <div class="main">

        <div id="b1" class="big active"><!-- image / video here --></div>
        <div id="b2" class="big"><!-- image / video here --></div>
        <div id="b3" class="big"><!-- image / video here --></div>

    </div>

    <div class="thumbnails">

        <a id="t1" class="active" href="#"><img src="images/thumb1.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
        <a id="t2" href="#"><img src="images/thumb1.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
        <a id="t3" href="#"><img src="images/thumb1.jpg" alt="#"/></a>

    </div>

</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".big").click(function () {
        var th = $(this);
        var id = this.id;
        id = id.substr(1);
        if (!($(th).hasClass("active"))){
            $(".active ").removeClass("active");
            $(th).addClass("active");
            $(".thumbnails ").find("#t"+id).addClass("active");
        }
    });
```

CSS:

```
.main div,.thumbnails div{display:none; opacity:0}
.active{display:block;opacity:1}
```

Answer (score 0):

**in html** set a attribute

```
    <a rel="1" href="#"><img src="images/thumb1.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a rel="2" href="#"><img src="images/thumb1.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a rel="3" href="#"><img src="images/thumb1.jpg" alt="#"/></a>

</div>
```

**IN JS**

```
  $('a').click(function(){ 
        var target = $(this).attr('rel');
        $('div.big').hide();
        $("div#"+target).show();
     })
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have multiple IDs, they are supposed to be unique. Update your divs yo use a custom HTML5 data attribute:

```
<div target-id="1" class="big"><!-- image / video here --></div>
<div target-id="2" class="big"><!-- image / video here --></div>
<div target-id="3" class="big"><!-- image / video here --></div>
```

And try this:

```
$('.thumbnails a').click(function(){ 
    var target = $(this).data('target-id');
    $('div').hide();
    $('div[target-id=' + target).show();
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div.big').on('click','a',function(){
 $('.thumbnails').find('div').hide();

 var id = $(this).data('id');
 var $e = $('#' + id);
 $e.show();
})
```

Note - since you cannot have 2 elements with the same id. I have assumed here that you put the id of the div to be shown in the attribute `data-id`

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
<div id="gallery">

<div class="main">

    <div rel="1" class="big"><!-- image / video here -->1 d</div>
    <div rel="2" class="big"><!-- image / video here -->2f</div>
    <div rel="3" class="big"><!-- image / video here -->3d</div>

</div>

<div class="thumbnails">
    <a id="1" href="#"><img src="images/thumb1.jpg" alt="#"/>1</a>
    <a id="2" href="#"><img src="images/thumb1.jpg" alt="#"/>2</a>
    <a id="3" href="#"><img src="images/thumb1.jpg" alt="#"/>3</a>

</div>
```

```
$('.big').click(function(){
   var cuu_id= $(this).attr('rel');
    $('a').hide();
    $("#"+cuu_id).show();
 });

.thumbnails a {display:none;}
```